# Pairwise crossproduct in Python

Tags: python, list

How can I get the list of cross product *pairs* from a list of arbitrarily long lists in Python?

### Example

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

`crossproduct(a,b)` should yield `[[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], ...]`.

Comment: It is called Cartesian product.

Comment: also known as the cross product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You're looking for [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) if you're on (at least) Python 2.6.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[4,5,6]
>>> itertools.product(a,b)
<itertools.product object at 0x10049b870>
>>> list(itertools.product(a,b))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: Note that for pre-2.6 use, you can simply copy-and-paste the pure Python implementation from the linked documentation.

Comment: `product()` is not restricted to two parameters thus usable for an arbitrary number of lists (listed themselves) as well. So you can do `list(itertools.product(*[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]))` to get `[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6),..`

Answer (score 106):

Since you asked for a list:

```
[(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
```

But you can avoid the overhead of a list if you're just looping through these by using generators instead:

```
((x, y) for x in a for y in b)
```

Behaves identically in a `for` loop but doesn't result in the creation of a `list`.

Comment: I prefer this method, but can't say why.  Maybe because the double looping is explicit?

Comment: Nicely pythonic.  Or as I like to say, a good example of pythontificocity.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a big fan of code that looks like what it does.

Comment: Sorry for the late bump. This looks nice. However, if the OP is looking for Cartesian product, won't this create duplicates and reversed pairs?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If `a` and `b` are not sets, and have duplicate elements within themselves, then yes, this can produce duplicate entries. `[(x, y) for x in [1, 1] for y in [2]]` would produce `[(1, 2), (1, 2)]`. But that's the result of applying an mathematical operation defined on sets on non-set input. Reversed pairs will not occur -- anything in the `a` iterable will never appear as the second element of a returned pair unless that element is also in the `b` iterable.

Comment: Explicit is always better than implicit.

Comment: plus 1 for generators.  I'm just starting to realize their power.  thanks.

Comment: Pythonic but 200 times slower than `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 23):

Using generators there is no need for itertools, simply:

```
gen = ((x, y) for x in a for y in b)

for u, v in gen:
    print u, v
```