# cross product in python of arbitrarily many lists

Tags: python, list, cartesian-product, cross-product

I know you can take the pairwise cross product of lists in the ways posted here: [Pairwise crossproduct in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541401/pairwise-crossproduct-in-python)

but I want to take a list L and a positive integer n and return the cross-product of L with itself n times. Is there a built in way to do this or will I just have to iterate the pairwise cross-product?

(edit: "cartesian product")

Comment: That's the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), not the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).
>
> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element
>   advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic
>   ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product
>   tuples are emitted in sorted order.
>
> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number
>   of repetitions with the optional repeat keyword argument. For example,
>   product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A).

So you just need to do

```
itertools.product(L, repeat=n)
```