# splitting a sequence into pair combinations

Tags: python, list

Apologies if I do not frame my question well, I'll try my best to do so:

How can I get a list to return every possible pair combination within it?

for instance

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to know how I can obtain a result like this:

```
a= [ [1,2], [1,3] , [1,4], [2,3] , [2,4] , [3,4] ]
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541401/pairwise-crossproduct-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in  itertools modules!

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> it.combinations([1,2,3,4],2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x106260fc8>
>>> list(it.combinations([1,2,3,4],2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: thanks, I shall have to look into the whole itertools module, seems really useful

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```